# implement both EntityFramework 6 and EntityFramework Core side-by-side in a n-tier solution

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

Here is an excerpt from [Getting Started with ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework 6](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/entity-framework-6.html):

> "The recommended way to use Entity Framework 6 in an ASP.NET Core 1.0
>   application is to put the EF6 context and model classes in a class
>   library project (.csproj project file) that targets the full
>   framework. Add a reference to the class library from the ASP.NET Core
>   project. "

**My Goal:** is to implement both EntityFramework 6 and EntityFramework Core side-by-side in a n-tier solution.

**Solution:**

- ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) with Individual User Accounts Authentication
- Windows Class Libraries (.dll) containing BLL & DAL

The reason for implementing EF 6 and EF Core side-by-side is due to:

- EF Core 1.x implementation issues (migrations, many-to-zero relationships)
- Individual User Accounts Authentication in ASP.NET Core have a dependency on Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext
- This use-case will implement BreezeJS which currently depends on Entity Framework 6

I can successfully add migrations to the ASP.NET Core Web Application as follows:

```
PM> EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

However, I get an exception when attempting to add migrations to the Windows class library:

```
PM> EntityFramework\Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

> Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s): "Type 
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject'
>   in assembly  'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation,
>   Version=14.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is
>   not marked as serializable." At
>   C:\Src\Hcs.NetCore\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:720
>   char:5
>   +     $domain.SetData('startUpProject', $startUpProject)
>   ...

If I unload the ASP.NET Core Web Application, then I can successfully add EF6 migrations to the Windows class library with the following steps:

```
PM> EntityFramework\enable-migrations
PM> EntityFramework\add-migration InitialCreate
```

Now I have the initial migration in both projects.

However, when I run the ASP.NET Core Web Application I get a couple of runtime exceptions:

If I have parameter-less constructor in my custom implementation of System.Data.Entity.DbContext, then I get the following runtime exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code …
>   Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified) …

That was remedied by removing the default constructor.

When I attempted to register a user, the following exception was thrown:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database
>   "xxx" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user
>   yyy\zzz'.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling)    at

Q - Am I on the right track? Is this now simply a SQL Server authentication issue? Or, are other issues involved?

Comment: Any ideas on how to run a .Net 4.6 MVC project with EF 6 and EF core?  I don't want to migrate all over to EF core at once, but really need some of the features to speed up imports and bulk updates.

Comment: [The EF Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) states that EF Core is cross-platform. My understanding is that in order to be cross-platform, EF Core must run in a .NET core application. However, [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/) lists .NET Framework 4.5.1 in the dependencies section. Perhaps someone else can say if it is possible to run EF Core in a .NET 4x application. FWIW, you may find the [feature comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features) to be informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## “Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s) exception:”

The `“Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s) exception:”` can be remedied by passing either `-StartupProject` or `-StartupProjectName` parameter in the following commands:

In the Package Manager Console, set the Default Project to the class library containing the EF6 context (Dna.Net.Application.DAL.EF6 in my case) and execute:

```
PM> EntityFramework\enable-migrations -StartupProject Dna.Net.App.DAL.EF6
PM> EntityFramework\add-migration InitialCreate -StartupProjectName Dna.Net.App.DAL.EF6
```

## “System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "xxx” requested by the login. The login failed.”

The `“System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "xxx” requested by the login. The login failed.”` exception can be remedied at runtime by clicking the **`[Apply Migrations]`** button when saving a new user account, **or**, at design-time by executing **`Update-Database`** as follows:

In the Package Manager Console, set the Default Project to the class library containing the EF6 context and execute:

```
PM> EntityFramework\Update-Database -StartupProject Dna.Net.Application.DAL.EF6
```

In the Package Manager Console, set the Default Project to the class library containing the EF Core context and execute:

```
PM> EntityFrameworkCore\Update-Database
```

At this point, I can inspect the databases using either Server Explorer or SQL Server Object Explorer.

The `Update-Database` commands have created unique databases for the EFCore and EF6 contexts.

This solution follows the guidelines contained in the Sample Application section of [Getting Started with ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6) with the following exception:

- I did not need to implement `IDbContextFactory`.

Now I can successfully perform the following tests:

- Add a user via the ASP.NET Core MVC Individual User Account scaffolding.
- Modify the (ASP.NET Core MVC scaffolded) HomeController.About() to persist and retrieve a custom entity to a custom System.Data.Entity.DbContext implementation.
- Modify About.cshtml to display the persisted custom entity.

Answer (score 1):

The EF6 commands don't know how to work with ASP.NET Core projects (they didn't exist when it was written). You'll probably have to unload these projects before running EF6 commands.

You may also be able to explicitly specify `-StartupProject` as the EF6 project to workaround the issue.

Comment: I have revised the question to include an excerpt from the ASP.NET Core doc's article. Unfortunately, the link to a sample project referenced in that article is throwing HTTP 404. @bricelam Are you saying that article is incorrect?

Comment: It's correct. That's the best way to avoid extension method conflicts. The runtime will work just fine. However, you may have to jump through a few hoops to get the design-time tools to work. Specifying `-StartupProject` might also avoid the issue.