# Azure Function : Enable-Migrations Exception calling “SetData” with “2” argument(s)

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-functions

Getting the below Error after command `enable-migrations -force`

I am using EntityFramework Version=6.1.3

```
Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s): "Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject' in assembly 
    'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable."
    At \6.0.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:609 char:5
    +     $domain.SetData('project', $project)
    +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SerializationException

    Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s): "Type
```

Comment: Any update? Have you solved the issue? If my answer doesn't solved the issue. I suggest you could post more codes about how you design the EF code first model.

Comment: I solve issue create separate model project

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the “Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s) exception:” error message means you don't set the right project name in your application.

There are two ways to solve this error.

One way is choosing right project name in the package manager console.

[image]

Then set the right project name in the package manager console.

[image]

Another way is directly pass the -StartupProject or -StartupProjectName paramete to the enable-migrations command.

More details, you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40565698/7609093).